# Show that stabilizer of i is isomorphic to $A_{n-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A_n$ denote the alternating group of even permutations made by $n$ symbols $1,2,3,\ldots, n$. Suppose $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots, n\}$ and $*:A_n\times A\rightarrow A$ be defined by
$$\sigma *i=\sigma(i)~\forall~(\sigma, I)\in A_n \times A$$

Now I have been able to show $*$ is a group action of $A_n$ on $A$. I also made to show that $Orb_{A_n}(i)=A$ and stab$_{A_n}(i)=A_n$for every $i\in A$ when $n\geq3$.

Now I am willing to show that for $n\geq 2$, the stabilizer stab$_{A_n}(i)\simeq A_{n-1}$. I get stuck here. How can $A_n$ be isomorphic to $A_{n-1}$ ?
Thanks in well advance.

Comment: A_n is not isomorphic to A_n-1. One way to see how the stabilizer of the element is isomorphic to A_n-1 is to realize that the elements that stabilize any letter include every cycle/product of cycles that do not contain the letter. This is precisely every even permutation of the n-1 other letters. Try to convince yourself that after a relabeling of letters you end up with A_n-1.

Answer (score 1):

The stabilizer of $i$ can't be $A_n$; otherwise by the orbit- stabilizer theorem the orbit would only have $1$ element.

The stabilizer is $A_{n-1}$. You are just looking at even permutations that fix $i$.  Namely, even permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,\hat i,\dots,n\}$.

Also, $A_n$ and $A_{n-1}$ have different orders, so can't be isomorphic.

This checks out with the aforementioned theorem, because $[A_n:A_{n-1}]=n$.